# They've lost themselves

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues

Can you solve the clues and work out how these things can get themselves back? Word lengths refer to the solutions before restoration to their original selves.

1. African hill. Yours truly, French (5)
2. All right, hey (4)
3. An interface for computer program (5)
4. A nocturnal creature (4)
5. Article hard to come by (5)
6. Before vehicle (6)
7. Criticize best grade, well below average (8)
8. Duke (9)
9. Everyone put up here (6)
10. Fool's gold (5)
11. Iceland good as in France (5)
12. In that case, son (5)
13. I yearn, I and others (7)
14. Me and the rest whip (5)
15. Muppet to swing round (7)
16. Opposing earlier (7)
17. Pardon extended (5)
18. Sail away with one (7)
19. Show off wide sash (6)
20. That so male principle (8)
21. Tipsy cake not quite fresh (6)
22. Tree county (7)
23. Uncovered crone with measure for printer (9)
24. Varsities (4)
25. Working teacher (5)

Comment: If these are cryptic clues, I believe it's a common thing to add the numbers of letters of the words corresponding.

Comment: OK, I'll do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think these are

> capital cities with initial letter omitted; i.e., *capitals* without their *capitals*, hence the title.

And here they all are. (Some done by Joe in comments; thanks, Joe.)

African hill. Yours truly, French (5)

> (S)KOPJE [Joe, comments]

All right, hey (4)

> (T)OKYO [Joe, comments]

An interface for computer program (5)

> (B)ANGUI

A nocturnal creature (4)

> (R)ABAT

Article hard to come by (5)

> (H)ARARE

Before vehicle (6)

> (Y)EREVAN

Criticize best grade, well below average (8)

> (I)SLAMABAD [found concurrently by Joe in comments]

Duke (9)

> (W)ELLINGTON

Everyone put up here (6)

> (T)ALLINN

Fool's gold (5)

> (N)ASSAU [Joe, comments]

Iceland good as in France (5)

> (L)ISBON [Joe, comments]

In that case, son (5)

> (A)THENS

I yearn, I and others (7)

> (L)ILONGWE [Joe, comments]

Me and the rest whip (5)

> (M)USCAT

Muppet to swing round (7)

> (B)ELMOPAN

Opposing earlier (7)

> (S)ANTIAGO [Joe, comments]

Pardon extended (5)

> (T)EHRAN

Sail away with one (7)

> (D)JIBOUTI

Show off wide sash (6)

> (N)AIROBI [Joe, comments]

That so male principle (8)

> (P)YONGYANG

Tipsy cake not quite fresh (6)

> (M)BABANE

Tree county (7)

> (T)ASHKENT [Joe, comments]

Uncovered crone with measure for printer (9)

> (C)OPENHAGEN [Joe, comments]

Varsities (4)

> (T)UNIS

Working teacher (5)

> (L)ONDON

Comment: Gareth McCaughan: Well done, this is correct. Can you explain what the title means?

Comment: capitals without capitals

Comment: I'm just deleting out my comments as they get moved into the post. You got the connection so I'm just filling in blanks at this point :P

Comment: OK, added some more of yours and mine

Comment: Just four left to do.

Comment: Three more to do.

Comment: An en is a printer's measure, notionally the width of a letter "n".

Comment: Just the tipsy cake to do now.

Comment: ... And all done.

Comment: And all correct. Excellent work, guys. You polished these off pretty quickly.